# Advice needed regarding Live Search with jQuery, AJAX, JSP/Servlet, MySQL and JSON?

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, ajax

So far I've found mixed responses on the topic.

I have a table with 2,000 (2k) records which gets updated about once a month with only a few records (5-10). Table structure is very simple:

```
id, name, data1, data2, data3
```

On the website I have a form and would like to add a live search to one of the fields based on item's name, so user can quickly select the right item. Later on based on the selection (id of the item) I do some calculation on the backend.

There will be quite a few users that access the form in real time.

My question is: what is the best way to implement live search?

a) Dump table once a month into JSON and use it with jQuery/AJAX

OR

b) jQuery/AJAX that call servlet with live MySQL search every time user types something in the field

**EDIT**: in case this is important. I have enough RAM on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are either making AJAX call to a controller that will parse a JSON or to a controller that will directly crawl DB I think - according to your DB settings and complexity - it should be about the same so you should take from DB directly for easier maintenance and simplicity.

If the query is going to be complex with multiple joins, you can try first to run the query in your SQL manager to have a preview of the speed!

[EDIT]

I also want to add that if your website has heavy traffic then it would be good to have a JSON to alight the calls to DB.

But in this case you will still have an AJAX call per new letter which is a lot.

So, the best solution - IMHO - is to fetch from DB the whole products list matching first letter on first letter input by user, then refine later (as user types in) in Javascript only so you don't need to make further calls to your server + it's very fast for the user experience.

I recommend you use JSON format for convenience to crawl in Javascript to refine matches.

Only if user changes first letter then refetch from server.